# Multiple drawables with ColorFilters to one PNG file

Tags: android, android-drawable, colorfilter

I have Drawables which have ColorFilters. I want save these drawables to one PNG file (one over other) with ColorFilters. I found only method with conversion of Drawable to Bitmap, but from what I saw this conversion remove ColorFilter. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: use LayerDrawable.draw()

Comment: of course make sure your drawable has the bounds set - setBounds() was called before calling draw()

Comment: if you don't want to use additional LayerDrawable you can still iterate over your list of Drawables and call their draw() method, that way you have more control how each Drawable is drawn (different sizes, scales, alpha, rotation etc)